# Android Studio - No Option to add dependencies?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, gradle

I want to add GooglePlayServices to an already existing project (Libgdx). But i have an problem, after i added them to the build.gradle file, they dont show up. I already installed GooglePlayServices using the SDK manager. What did i do wrong ..?

When i go to Project Structure under the dependencies tab, there only 3 different options :

1. Add Jar or Folder ( selfexplained )
2. Add Library
3. Add Module Dependencies ( When i click this, im able to add my Main or Core Module as an Dependencies. No other options )

Heres an picture of my Project Tree:

[image: ProjectTree]

Heres an picture of my Project Structure :

[image: Project Structure]

The only Dependencie i can import is the Module one... Thats strange.

[image: ModuleDependencie]

And heres what my whole build.gradle ( I post all because i have totally no idea wheres the error part ) i marked the lines, which i added for GooglePlayService :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "ParallelOrigin"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.5'
    roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
}

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    compile "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-android:1.2.0"


   //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //--------------------------Added by myself-----------------------------------//
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//


    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:23.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:$ashleyVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-bullet:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.0"
    compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.13.4"
    compile "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils-box2d:0.13.4"
    compile "de.tomgrill.gdxdialogs:gdx-dialogs-core:1.2.0"

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //--------------------------Added by myself-----------------------------------//
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:23.2.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
 delete ".project"
}
```

Thanks for your help and your time !

Comment: looks like that you already added it, try to sync your project again ?

Comment: @king already did that, i also restarted my pc. But those GooglePlayService Dependencies dont show up. No dependencies show up, only my 2 foldern (android and core)... I created this project via libgdx generator. Its kinda strange, i compared the Android Studio made project and the libgdx one. The android studio one got much other options. There i also can add dependencies without any iusses.

Comment: kind of silly but try to invalidate cashes from file menu

Comment: @MCZ Thanks for your answer ! Im gonna try that. But the Strange thing is, that theres the Option to add Dependencies on an native Android Studio App. There some other options..

Comment: @MCZ those options arent avaible on the libgdx Import.

Comment: Have you add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` add the bottom of your build.gradle? and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the iusse !

This only happened because my project wasnt a gradle one. I only needed to migrate it and then i could import those maven dependencies !